# JSON response not being shown inside the cell

Tags: ios, json, uitableview, swift3, cell

I’m creating a Tableview and trying to include in the cell one information that I receive through a JSON from an API. 
The information (JSON) is being received very well and recorded correctly inside the variable. 
However, what I could find is that as the information is received with a small “delay” is not being set as the cell’s label text at the cell creation moment, which is being set with the default variable content. 
I guess the solution would be to update the label at the moment I parse the JSON content, right? How do I do this? (Update a cell’s label after it is already created) 
Any other insight/ solution is greatly appreciated.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, AddStock {

    let operacoesAcoes = ListaOperacoes()
    var todasAsOperacoes : [Operacao] = []

    @IBOutlet weak var acoesTableView: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        acoesTableView.delegate = self
        acoesTableView.dataSource = self
        acoesTableView.register(UINib(nibName: "StandardStockListCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "standardCell")
        operacoesAcoes.consolidaAcoes()
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return operacoesAcoes.carteiraAcoes.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "standardCell", for: indexPath) as! StandardStockListCell
        let informacaoCompletaAcao = operacoesAcoes.carteiraAcoes[indexPath.row]

        cell.codigoTextField.text = informacaoCompletaAcao.codigoAcao
        cell.nomeTextField.text = informacaoCompletaAcao.nomeAcao
        cell.quantidadeTotal.text = String(informacaoCompletaAcao.quantidadeTotal)
        cell.precoMedioLabel.text = String(format: "%.2f", informacaoCompletaAcao.precoMedio)

       // 
       // This is the part of the code that should set one label with a value returned from "buscaCotacao" but it does not work
       // because at the time the cell is displayed it is still not updated from JSON information:
       // Note: the buscaCotacao func is working fine 

        cell.precoAtualLabel.text = buscaCotacao(ativo: informacaoCompletaAcao.codigoAcao)

        return cell
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to reload the table view on the main thread after receiving and parsing the JSON.

`self.acoesTableView.reloadData()`

Answer (score 0):

I did some research and tryouts, and could figure out a very simple (and now obvious) solution to update my Label after the result of the request is received:
- I call the function which retrieves the information from an API to update the cell ("buscaCotacao"), including the [cell row] information
- I update the cell's label from inside the function, which will happen only after the reply is received:

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

```
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "standardCell", for: indexPath) as! StandardStockListCell
    let informacaoCompletaAcao = operacoesAcoes.carteiraAcoes[indexPath.row]

    cell.codigoTextField.text = informacaoCompletaAcao.codigoAcao
    cell.nomeTextField.text = informacaoCompletaAcao.nomeAcao
    cell.quantidadeTotal.text = String(informacaoCompletaAcao.quantidadeTotal)
    cell.precoMedioLabel.text = "R$ "+String(format: "%.2f", informacaoCompletaAcao.precoMedio)

    buscaCotacao(ativo: informacaoCompletaAcao.codigoAcao, for: cell, indexPath: indexPath)

    return cell
}
```

And in the function:

func buscaCotacao (ativo: String, for cell: StandardStockListCell, indexPath: IndexPath) {

```
    let finalURL = "https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_INTRADAY&interval=1min&apikey=XXXXXXXXXXXXXX&outputsize=compact&symbol=" + ativo

    Alamofire.request(finalURL, method: .get)
        .responseJSON { response in
            if response.result.isSuccess {
                let resultadoJSON : JSON = JSON(response.result.value!)
                let resultado = Float (self.parseResultado(json: resultadoJSON))!
                cell.precoAtualLabel.text = "R$ "+String(format: "%.2f", resultado)
                self.cotacoes[ativo] = resultado

            } else {
                cell.precoAtualLabel.text = "N/D"
                print("Error: \(response.result.error!)")
            }
    }
}
```